Configure List of Figures to reference first page not last in Table of Contents
The problem is when I use the line below I get the correct page numbering as the first but I also get the last page number of the List of Figures (LOF) whereas without it I only get the incorrect last page of the LOF. I just want the first on page x not xiv.
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename} 

The template this is based off of can be found here and the edit I made is line 938.
Source: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cal-poly-thesis-template/vvqzkxgchkvc
Google Search "Cal Poly Thesis Template Overleaf" by Andrew Guenther and David D. Marshall
Thanks!


I imagine that most of the time the \listoffigures only takes one page.
The hard part was keeping the float queue from overflowing during the test.
\documentclass{book}

\let\oldlistfigurename=\listfigurename
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\oldlistfigurename
  \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\oldlistfigurename}}

\newcounter{foo}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\loop\ifnum\value{foo}<60
  \stepcounter{foo}%
  \chapter{Test \thefoo}
  Some test here.
  
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5\textheight}
    \caption{Test \thefoo}
  \end{figure}
\repeat

\end{document}


The problem is this was for a thesis and the list of figures takes 5 pages (4.25) so I need it to work, but I didn't realize the only change to prevent the 2nd erroneous one was to eliminate it from the main.tex when since the naming can be done correctly in the cls file. All corrected now based on my answer (with links to his github and I think he pushed the changes)

If anyone was curious here was the solution from Github with the Overleaf Contents:

Issue: https://github.com/CalPolyCSC/thesis-template/issues/53

Solution: https://github.com/CalPolyCSC/thesis-template/pull/54/commits/a25080c1a590d4293febaa8680e9173353e72c70


Why I was getting 2 results is because the " \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{listfigurename}} " should have been removed or commented out to prevent replication in the main.tex.
